# I'm struggling with changing this loop as asynchronous nodejs

Tags: node.js, loops, promise, async-await

- in a loop -

  1. get some data from mysql
  2. insert the data into specific array ( at the index of i)

but as you know, 'i' increases much earlier than I expected.
I know it's a problem with a sync/async proplem of nodejs.
I wanna change it into synchronous function, but it's too confusing maybe because it's my first time...

```
...
dbconn.pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {

...

    for (var i = 0; i < search_result.length; i++) {
        console.log("1, i here : "+i)
        conn.query(sql_getId_and_count, [search_result[i].address], function (err, result) {

              console.log("2.i here:" + i)
              if (err) console.error(err)
              else {
                   console.log("here : " + result[0].counter)
              }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: actually you don't need to make it synchronous thats not nodejs meant for, instead let it be asynchronous and I think you just want to access variable `i` inside query then please use `let` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use while loop.
Note that node.js is not made to interrupt the while loop.

You can also use process.nextTick(), and write the implementation inside it.
eg : process.nextTick(function() {} )